# What is ~ means in Linux how it works?

Tags: linux

What is ~ means in Linux how it works?

```
cd ~/
```

I am using it with CD command, but don't know how it is working.

Answer (score 2):

`~` refers to your home directory, so using it with `cd` will switch to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to home directories of the users. It can used a shortcut like if you have navigated to some folder like /var/logs etc and then you type `cd ~` then it will return you back to the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

This `~` symbol :

means going to your **home** directory